# How to find the horizontal, vertical and diagonal correaltion between two images

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to do the analysis of face region encryption technique in java. I have detected and encrypted the face region , now i have to do the analysis.
I have found out the correlation coefficient of two images but unable to understand the formula for finding the horizontal, vertical and diagonal correlation. What is the formula to find the horizontal, vertical and diagonal correlation between two images?

Comment: You probably mean autocorrelation ? Just compare shifted versions.

Comment: I meant, as we calculate the correlation coefficient of two images, how to calculate the horizontal, vertical and diagonal correlation coefficients...?

Comment: just compare shifted versions.